# Fille/jeune femme/femme

Tags: vocabulaire

I'm wondering what would be the right way to say "*the club is full of **girls/women***" if these girls/women are between let's say 18-25? Might ***filles*** work or is ***jeunes femmes*** more adequate? And what about if one is talking about ***boys/men*** of the same age? To me the word ***garçon*** seems to primarily refer to younger boys. I guess ***mecs*** might work but maybe there's also a less familiar way of referring to males in this age range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## About boys/men

**Jeunes hommes** is used quite naturally for non-maried men of this age. **Garçons** would be said by someone of the same age, **hommes** would be said by someone younger.

## About girls/women

Considering the same range of age, **femmes** and even **jeunes femmes** tend to make them older. **Filles** is more natural than **garçons**.

## About both

As long as we are talking about young adult girls, it mostly depends on the age of the one who speaks, but the choice can also be driven by the context.

For example :

1. If one wants to emphasize that a nightclub is full of girls of their age or younger, they will say **"cette boite de nuit est pleine de filles"**.
2. If one is older than most people in the night club and wants to emphasize that the girls are old enough to be consenting, they will say **"cette boite de nuit est pleine de jeunes femmes"**.

## About "mec", "meuf" and "nana"

**Mecs** and **meufs** are much more familiar but also more equivocal about the relative age.

**Nana** is quite old and not very used by millennials or younger people anymore.

## Sidenote

I'm a French man from France. I think most French people would agree with this answer, but opinions on this subject may differ in other countries.

Comment: Pourquoi autant de caractères en gras ? C'est perturbant pour la lecture.

Comment: C'est simplement pour distinguer les mots français du reste du texte. Je trouvais ça plus agréable que des guillemets.

Comment: Pas convaincu que *nana* soit si vieilli que ça. Un "sondage" (très limité) sur une collégienne de 12 ans me remonte qu'il n'y a pas de problème à utiliser *nana*. En revanche, *nénette* est lui certainement démodé.

Answer (score 0):

If you say ***mecs***, you can also say ***nanas*** although it doesn't really state how old they might be, otherwise ***jeunes femmes*** is right for this age range.

You might also say *il y a surtout beaucoup de **jeunes adultes**, hommes et femmes, dans ce club*.

See also: [On an apparent "masstermization" phenomenon in contemporary informal French: “il y a de la jolie nana par ici”](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/36573/on-an-apparent-masstermization-phenomenon-in-contemporary-informal-french-il) and [Utilisation de « mec/meuf »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17315/utilisation-de-mec-meuf)

Comment: « Cette boite est pleine de jeunes »,  dans une boite (de nuit) il y a mélange de genres, ce qui n'est pas toujours vrai dans les clubs ± privés.

Answer (score 0):

Dans le contexte d'une soirée en discothèque, **filles** passe bien sans être trop familier. L'équivalent masculin est plus **gars** que **garçons**.

Plus soutenu, il y a **jeunes femmes** et **jeunes hommes** (ou **jeunes gens**).

Plus familier, il y a **nanas**, **meufs**, **gonzesses**... et **mecs**, **keums**...